# DFC reading a file

Tags: java, documentum

I am using the DFC to access documentum. I am trying to read a file. I have the r_object_id and I now wish to return the document assoicated with this. How would I do this in java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

assuming you also have a valid session with at least read access to the file:

```
String docId= getDocId();
IDfSysObject doc = (IDfSysObject)session.getObject(new DfId(docId));
ByteArrayInputStream stream = doc.getContent();
```

see the javadocs for the return type [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) for info on how to process the return.  Also I've noticed you've been asking quite a few Documentum Foundation Classes questions.  depending on the version of the DFCs you are using, you can find the javadocs online at either [powerlink](http://powerlink.emc.com) or [subscribenet](https://emc.subscribenet.com/) and probably answer many of your own questions.